# Why history command doesn't work in shell

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I'm working on Mac OS Sierra Shell.
Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
contenu=`df`
echo ${contenu}
```

When I execute this shell, I can see the result of `df`.

However, when I try to print the first line of `history`, I can just see an empty line.

```
#!/bin/bash
contenu=`history | head -1`
echo ${contenu}
```

I've also executed the same command on the terminal and it worked very well.

```
user$ history | head -1
```

When I execute the command above, I can see what I'm waiting for. For example:

> ```
>    161 ls -l
> ```

Comment: Whats the out of `history | head -1` when you run it interactively?

Comment: @heemayl  well, I can get what I want, meaning that the first line of `history` is shown.

Comment: It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Are you running those two commands in the shell, or in a separate script? The latter will start a subshell/session (whatever you like to call it), with an empty history.

Comment: @bansi  I really dont know what to say... Is it because I used OSX instead of Linux?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script

Comment: If you repeatedly run `echo ${contenu}`, do you get empty line each time? If not, perhaps your `~/.bash_history` file had an empty line for the line you were trying to fetch with `echo ${contenu}`. I am OSX and have no issue with either running `history | head -1` or `echo ${contenu}`

Comment: For the record, there is no "Mac OS Sierra Shell.". That will be bash by default.

Comment: @zedfoxus  yeah, I repeatedly run `echo ${contenu}` and I get many empty lines...

Comment: don't know, tested with linux and it works.

Comment: try a different line or just try `history | head`

Comment: @bansi  still empty.....

Comment: What's the output of `history | head -10`? What's the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: @Evert   oooh, it works! Thanks. Plz redirect my question or answer it.

Comment: @Yuhui very nice. What was the issue and how did you fix it?

Comment: @zedfoxus  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script

Comment: @Yuhui That link has many answers. Which answer helped? Was it just `set -o history`?

Comment: @zedfoxus  yes. Well it is not the real-time history but at least, I can get history.

Comment: @Yuhui Thank you for sharing what worked best for you. Much appreciated.